# How to show div when click on some <td> row using angular

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have this table:
[Click here to view photo for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRSpr.png)

[image]

I want when clicking on some of these rows in the table to display div(or to active "edit" button who displaying this div that I want).
I'm using angular.
How can I do this?
Can someone help me?
I'm new at programming and I'm sorry if my questions are not very clear.
I have a code:

```
<button id="editbtn">Edit</button>
<button id="addbtn">Add</button>

<div class="hideShow" style="display: none;">
<div class="form">
<form ng-submit="saveItem(userForm.$valid)" name="userForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="database_address">Потребителско име</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" required ng-model="activeItem.username" placeholder="Потребителско Име..." />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Парола*</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" ng-model="activeItem.passwordString"  />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Потвърждаване на парола*</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" ng-model="activeItem.passwordConfirm"  />
            </div>
              <p ng-show="(activeItem.passwordString != activeItem.passwordConfirm)" style="color:red">Паролите не съвпадата</p>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Оператор</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" required id="username" ng-model="activeItem.name" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" type="submit">Запиши</button>
    <!--<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" type="submit">Добавяне на нов</button>-->
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="hideShow1" style="display: none;">
<div class="form">
<form ng-submit="createUser(userForm1.$valid)" name="userForm1">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="database_address">Потребител</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="usernamee" placeholder="Потребителско Име..." />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Парола</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="passwordd" required id="password"   />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Оператор</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="namee" required id="username"  />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary"  type="submit">Запиши</button> <!--ng-click="createUser()"-->
    <!--<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" type="submit">Добавяне на нов</button>-->
</form>
</div>
</div>
<!----------------------------FORM FOR ADD USER---------------------------->

</body>
```

```
<script>
$('button').click(function(){    
  if(this.id == 'editbtn'){
    $('.hideShow').show();
    $('.hideShow1').hide();
  }else{
    $('.hideShow').hide();
    $('.hideShow1').show();
  }
})

</script>
```

Comment: This question looks very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55236601/how-to-hide-div2-when-button1-is-clicked-and-show-div1-angular Are you and [@Mitko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11199549/mitko) in the same class?

Comment: yes we are,thanks !

Comment: And also scripts code shows it is `jquery` not `angularjs`.

Comment: Mixing AngularJS like this is asking for trouble.

Comment: See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: I did this. Thanks to all. But how I can mark this row that I clicked on(with color blue for example, like options menu)?